# SqlDataReader not returning any records with using sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datareader

My Client upgraded his sql server from 2000 to 2008. It seems the `sqldatareader` now does not return any data. I put this code in vb.net just to see what it could be:

```vb
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim myCommand1 As SqlCommand
    Dim myDataReader1 As SqlDataReader
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim strsql3 As String = "select * from table"

    myCommand1 = New SqlCommand(strsql3, myConnection)

    '''saw on a post to try this command; it didn't help either
    'myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'executing the command and assigning it to connection

    myDataReader1 = myCommand1.ExecuteReader()
    MsgBox(myDataReader1.HasRows)

    While myDataReader1.Read()
        MsgBox("in the while")
    End While

    MsgBox("not in the while")

End Sub
```

It doesn't get any data even though there is data in the database. Did anyone else face this?

Thanks for any help,
Arthur

Comment: You don't have any data in that table or you are looking at the wrong database.  Happens a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you are really connecting to the database? Put a Try/Catch block in the code to see if its throwing an error. The SQL data reader should work with any and all SQL versions.

Comment: Check your connection string and confirm that you are connecting to the expected server and database.

Comment: You say "there is data in the database".  I presume you're using SSMS with the same query from your code to verify this.  I'd put a break point on `myConnection.Open()`, step over, and investigate your connection.  Is it connecting the the sql server instance and database you are expecting it to?

Comment: Yes I confirmed I was using the correct connection.

Comment: Yes I confirmed I was using the correct connection.   Below is a sample connection string: Dim strConnection1 As String = "Data Source=Someip;Initial Catalog=TEST_Table;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=stack;"     When I change the Catalog to TEST_tables  I get an error Cannot open database  Test_tables requested by login.  When I put it back to TEST_table I get no error.   Also when I put a select to table that doesnt exist; I get invalid object name.   So I know it going to the correct database.

Comment: When I put a break point on this code:
        myDataReader1 = myCommand1.ExecuteReader(); it executes but hasrows = false isclosed=false fieldcount=11

Comment: Try running Sql Profiler and then run your application.  You should see the query when it is sent to Sql Server.  If you see no query, then likely it is not connecting.  Do you have any try/catch blocks in the code?  Have you checked the Windows Application Event logs?

Comment: I see the sql coming into sql profiler;  i can take the query and paste it in sql server and get results;  no results in asp page:(

Comment: installed locally sql server express and tried to connect to that; the code return records.  some it must be some setting on my client sql server 2008 server?  I don't know enough on sql server to tell him what to change.

any help?

Comment: seems somone else had this issue; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/9a099303-32a3-4671-aba4-3004cb716bde/sqldatareader-returns-no-rows

Does anyone know what this means:

A colleague did some poking around with cliconfg.exe and discovered that creating an alias for the named pipe solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 doesn't have an instance name ex. `SERVER` where most of SQL Server 2008 has been installed with instance name ex. `SERVER\SQLEXPRESS` so just check your connection string  because you are probably using wrong server name.

Comment: [SQL Server 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174516(v=sql.80).aspx) can be installed as a default instance or a named instance.